# Field::setLong behave differently with Long and long fields in a class

Tags: java, reflection, field, wrapper, primitive-types

I have one very strange problem with my code.
When I run it, I get exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field lesson12.TestReflectionRepository.Main$TestSetLong.LongField to (long)23132
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:195)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.setLong(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:120)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setLong(Field.java:1021)
> at lesson12.TestReflectionRepository.Main.main(Main.java:15)

I don't understand what it means. If I use type `Long` for the variable `l` I also get the same exception on the same line. I think, it depends on what type is used in the class, `long` or `Long`. But I think, it shouldn't work like this.
Why does it happen? What's wrong I do?

```
public class Main {
    public static class TestSetLong {
        public Long LongField;
        public long longField;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestSetLong obj = new TestSetLong();
        Class cobj = obj.getClass();
        Field longField = cobj.getField("longField"), LongField = cobj.getField("LongField");
        long l = 23132L;//if I use Long I also get this exception on the same line
        longField.setLong(obj, l);
        LongField.setLong(obj, l);
    }
}
```

I use OpenJDK 11.0.12+7-b1504.40 amd64, run it in Intellij IDEA 2021.2.3.

Comment: `setLong()` is only for the primitive `long`. Use `set()` for the non-primitive `Long`.

Comment: Is everything so obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JavaDoc for `Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) you can:

- use [`Field.set(Object, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) to set reference field and primitive fields

> If the underlying field is of a primitive type, an unwrapping conversion is attempted to convert the new value to a value of a primitive type. If this attempt fails, the method throws an IllegalArgumentException.

- use [`Field.setLong(Object, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#setLong(java.lang.Object,long)) only to set fields of (primitive) type `long`

> Sets the value of a field as a `long` on the specified object. This method is equivalent to set(obj, lObj), where lObj is a Long object and lObj.longValue() == l.

Note that this description mentions the automatic unwrapping that occurs in `set(Object, Object)` - but it nowhere gives a hint that automatic wrapping might be allowed.

Comment: But why do they write about conversion if there is no warranty for it?

Comment: @DavidBlbulyan the unwrapping (unboxing) conversion is always done if you use `Field.set(Object, Object)` to set a primitive field. There is never a boxing conversion done in `Field.set(Object, long)`. What other warranty do you want?

Comment: I thought about the warranty for boxing a primitive type if I use `setLong(Object, long)`

Comment: @DavidBlbulyan autoboxing happens in expressions and is something the java compiler inserts for you into the generated code - for example in an argument of a method call (i.e. if you call `Field.set(Object, Object)` with a `long` value as second parameter.) The method `Field.setLong(Object, long)` takes a `long` as second parameter and its second argument is therefore not subject to autoboxing. And what `Field.setLong(Object, long)` does is explicitly stated as "setting a `long` field". A method is not an expression and its implementation is not required to do autoboxing conversions.